# Computing expectations of Wiener process $(1+W_t)\frac{C}{C+KW_t}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm trying to derive a property, for which I need to evaluate the following.

$W_t$ is a Wiener process, and I'm interested in finding:
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E} \left( (1+W_t)\frac{C}{C+KW_t}\right)$$
where $C$ and $K$ are constants.

---

I know that both $\mathbb{E}(W_t)=0$ and that processes are independent with time. That is, $W_{t, t-s}$ is independent of $W_{t-s, 0}$ and hence the expectation can be computed as a product of expectations.

In this case, the processes are not independent. I assume $W_t$ has normal increments $N(0, \sigma^2)$. Let $Z(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}(X) & = \int^\infty_{-\infty} x f(x) dx\\
& = \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{CZ(x)}{C+KZ(x)} xdx + \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{C}{C+KZ(x)}x dx
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Is everything correct up-to now? From here, I don't really know how to proceed?

Comment: $\frac{C}{C+KW_t}$ is a constant term?

Comment: @NN2 It's not - I meant that it evaluates to a constant as $\mathbb{E}(KW_t)=0$. Is that not the case?

Comment: The distribution of $W_t$ at time $t$ is $P(W,t) = \exp[-W^2/(2\sigma^2 t)]/\sqrt{2\pi t}$. Therefore the expectation you seek is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty C(1+W)/(C+KW) P(W,t) dW,$ which differs from what you wrote in the last line. I am guessing you won't find a closed form for this without using a series of special functions.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Thanks. I guess it's only an easy case if $K=0$ in my case.